# Cron job schedule to strem via RTP audio file

Tags: bash, audio, cron, asterisk

I have Asterisk 1.8.28 based PBX and I want to Intercom or Page some audio files at different times daily, I have Cisco SPA508G working as RTP receiver connected to my amplifier and bunch of speakers, I use the following context to do announcements [PAGER] exten => 800,1,Dial(MulticastRTP/basic/224.168.168.168:34560) and works fine if I do it manually by dialing ext.800 I created extension 800 that tigers Asterisk to do MulticastRTP to IP:224.168.168.168:34560 so I need bash script that can be executed daily via cron job but I am not sure what player and hot to play my file /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en/test.mp3 Any help will be very appreciated, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions to this is using [Asterisk call files](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Call+Files).

Using bash, you can create a text file following the format in the link then move the file to /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing.

You would be better off converting the recording to another format such as WAV to reduce transcoding load.